# Load balancing for website

Tags: load, hosting, nameservers

I have a website which is about to receive loads of traffic and I would like to setup some kind of load balancing. I want to make sure the website is up and running when the traffic comes in. I have 2 dedicated servers (both with WHM, CPanel and registered name servers) and I was wondering if by simply adding additional name servers to the domain name would do the trick. That would mean that I would have the following:

ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com for the first server and ns1.domain.net and ns2.domain.net for the second one. It's just, that I didn't try anything like this before. I've noticed there are paid services online for achieving this.

I am looking to be covered in case one of the servers goes down.

Any thoughts on are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "which is about to receive" . . . Yeah.

Comment: Well, thanks Mob. English is not my native language. I thought this site was about tech stuff.. not grammar. Your ... you're the best

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple of ways of doing this:-
1) Purchase a hardware load balancer to split the load between the 2 servers
2) Round Robin DNS - set 2 entries for you domains www record. 1 for each server - so, for instance, www goes to 1.1.1.1 and the other www A record goes to 1.1.1.2

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You dont need paid software for load balancing. You can use a reverse proxy like nginx to balance load across your web servers. Alternatively you can use DNS too; but its fraught with some problems. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)